# how to create a news feed app with Parse?

Tags: database, parse-platform, feed

Recently, I learned using Parse.com.
As we created an empty database, we could post our data (post,comment, etc), and retrieve them from Parse.

My issue is, I would like to create a news feed app for practicing, but I don't know how to connect the news feed (title, summary, image, url to webview) with my Parse backend.

Do you guys have any idea/thought about creating this kind of app?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To link it with the backend you need to do a few things:

1. Go to settings >> keys. Make sure you have put the correct keys in whatever app you are developing. (You will generally always need the Application ID and Client Key). If this is an iOS app, in your `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` put in `[Parse setApplicationId:@"yourId" clientKey:@"yourClientId"];`
2. To create the "News" objects, go to Core >> Data and click "+ Add Class" From there you can add columns (i.e. title, summary, image, url). (You can make your own items in there.)
3. To retrieve the data, this depends on what kind of app you're making. You will use the `PFQuery` class to obtain the data. You can find more at this link: https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFQuery.html. If you're making an iOS app, you'll write something this in a UITableView:

   ```
   PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"News"];
   // Any additional steps to limit the received data.
   NSArray *data = [query findObjects];
   ```

Comment: Hi hhyder, I get stuck at the second step. I would like to get news feed from some popular websites such as CNN, USA today, etc. Do I have to make my own items one by one from these websites and save it into my backend?

Comment: Hi Shumin, sorry I didn't understand what kind of news you wanted! You will need to create the class, (so step 2 is a 30 second process) but to actually _get_ news listings, you'll have to use something besides parse (that's just where you'll store it). You can use news APIs (http://www.programmableweb.com/news/81-news-apis-digg-fanfeedr-and-clearforest/2012/02/01)- which can be called from the app- and save the results into Parse. You can use `[Object setObject: forKey:]`

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Anypic Tutorial](https://parse.com/tutorials/anypic). It is a great example of how to create a newsfeed-style app on the iOS platform with step-by-step details taking you from design to implementation.

Comment: Hi Russell, I checkout the link. It looks more like an Instagram app. Basically, it's sharing data. But what if I want to make a newsfeed app based on data from popular website such as USA today, CNN, etc. ? Thanks.

Comment: Ah, when most people say newsfeed-style app they are referring to something similar to Facebook's newsfeed. To achieve what you're after you will first have to aggregate content from all of the various media outlets, which will require a substantial amount of effort to accomplish in an efficient and legal way. Look into content aggregation using the respective APIs from the different media sources.